# Big font on the 'click on this box to dismiss' text

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

[image]

Comment: Please discuss.

Comment: the font is too big .

Comment: @MNight What's your opinion for a solution then?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi at least make it smaller than the white text .

Comment: For the record, I do nto have this issue that you are saying exists as a bug. This issue seems localized to you. what's the browser you're using?

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix  it has been fixed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated [in comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1553/big-font-on-the-click-on-this-box-to-dismiss-text#comment2122_1553) this has been fixed and can be considered as answered.